# Hide informations from java console

Tags: java, applet, console

Is it possible to hide some informations from java console? My applet grab data from external website. Unfortunately, in URL there are some informations i'd like to hide. But when i launch my applet and java console, set trace level = 5, i can see something like 
`network: Connecting url_here`
Is it possilbe to hide this information?

Comment: Even if you hide things from being displayed in the console, the URL will always be visible for packet tracers like WireShark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possilbe to hide this information?

No, it is not possible for the applet to suppress that information.  Your site can hide the information by offering a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799006/in-java-how-can-i-redirect-system-out-to-null-then-back-to-stdout-again) to work fine, if you dont mind that all sysout logging is removed from the java console:

```
try {
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            //DO NOTHING
        }
        public void write(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
            //DO NOTHING
        }
    }));
} catch (Exception e) {
    // ignore
}
```

Comment: This just turns my own `System.out.println(...)` off, but external console output (like `network: Connecting`) is not affected. It's a part of Java security sandboxing I guess.