# How to suppress stdout for Stanford NLP ColumnDataClassifier.makeClassifier() function

Tags: java, nlp, classification, stanford-nlp

I am making a call to `edu.stanford.nlp.classify.ColumnDataClassifier.makeClassifier()`, and I need to block the std out that it generates. I tried setting `displayedColumn=-1` in the .prop file, but it does not see to me help. The following is the console output `makeClassifier()` generates that I want to eliminate. Can someone help?

Console output:

```
QNMinimizer called on double function of 1596 variables, using M = 15.
               An explanation of the output:
Iter           The number of iterations
evals          The number of function evaluations
SCALING        <D> Diagonal scaling was used; <I> Scaled Identity
LINESEARCH     [## M steplength]  Minpack linesearch
                   1-Function value was too high
                   2-Value ok, gradient positive, positive curvature
                   3-Value ok, gradient negative, positive curvature
                   4-Value ok, gradient negative, negative curvature
               [.. B]  Backtracking
VALUE          The current function value
TIME           Total elapsed time
|GNORM|        The current norm of the gradient
{RELNORM}      The ratio of the current to initial gradient norms
AVEIMPROVE     The average improvement / current value
EVALSCORE      The last available eval score

Iter ## evals ## <SCALING> [LINESEARCH] VALUE TIME |GNORM| {RELNORM} AVEIMPROVE EVALSCORE

Iter 1 evals 1 <D> [M 1.000E-1] 6.808E-1 0.00s |3.890E-1| {1.111E-2} 0.000E0 -
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing Stanford NLP in detail (it might be, that they offer some redirect via API... check that in advance!), but what you always can do, is redirect the **whole** stderr and stdout, by using `System.setOut(PrintStream)` and/or `System.setErr(PrintStream)` and providing your own `PrintStream`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sorry I must have mentioned before, I tried overriding write() as suggested here but surprisingly the makeClassifier still dumps the output to stdout.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799006/in-java-how-can-i-redirect-system-out-to-null-then-back-to-stdout-again)