# Suppress stdout / stderr from Desktop.browse(uri);

Tags: java

I am working on writing a console application that, depending on the menu item selected, pop open the user's web browser to a predefined URL. To achieve this, I am using the [`Desktop`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class in the following way (abridged):

```
    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();

    ...

    String path = "https://www.google.com/";
    desktop.browse(URI.create(path));
```

The problem that I am having, is that the `browse` method seems to print text to *stdout* / *stderr*, even though the URL has been opened properly; this messes with my console prompts.

> How can I tell `Desktop.browse()` to not print anything to sdtout / stderr?

**edit**

This seems to be due to the fact that the managed OS that I am running has a wrapper around *firefox*, whose shebang is defined as `#!/bin/bash -x` causing the script to execute verbosely.

Comment: just tried on OSX with Chrome as default browser, there nothing is printed. It probably is the script. But Desktop.browse() is delegated to DesktopPeer.browse() which is a native implementation so yo I don't think that you will have a chance to get the stdout/stderr from the OS process.

Comment: Just a thought, but would calling `System.setOut/setErr()` just before calling `desktop.browse()` work?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4799195), trying to set both Out and Err to a null stream, has no effect - the output I am seeing in my console appears to never come through any of the Java PrintStreams, as @ PJ has said - this may just be the nature of the call in that it will execute a native impl.