# Redirect jar output when called via jpype in python

Tags: java, python, jpype

I'm calling code in a jar file using jpype in python. The java code prints a bunch of output to stdout, which I'd like to just redirect to /dev/null. How would I do this? I can't modify the java code (since it's an external project).

Here is my python code:

```
import jpype
import jpype.imports
jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), '-Djava.class.path=%s' % astral)
jpype.imports.registerDomain('phylonet')
from phylonet.coalescent import CommandLine
CommandLine.main(['-i', input_file, '-o', output_file])
jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

Fortunately I can redirect the output that I need to a file, but I still get a lot of undesirable output directly to stdout. I'm calling multiple instances in a process pool, so I end up with garbled output from multiple instances of the java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stealing from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799006/in-java-how-can-i-redirect-system-out-to-null-then-back-to-stdout-again) and then translating to Python/JPype

```
import jpype
import jpype.imports
from jpype.types import *

jpype.startJVM(convertStrings=False)

from java.lang import System
from java.io import PrintStream, File

original = System.out
System.out.println("Hello")
System.setOut(PrintStream(File("NUL"))) # NUL for windows, /dev/null for unix
System.out.println("Big")
System.setOut(original)
System.out.println("Boy")
```

If you need to be neutral to the OS, you would need to compile your own NullPrintStream concept as it is currently not possible to extend a class in JPype.

Comment: I also ended up using System.setErr() as well to redirect stderr. Nice work!