# In Java, how can I redirect System.err for a specific method invocation?

Tags: java, console, stdout, stderr

Say I have some method `method()` in Java which invokes series of methods corresponding to a stacktrace structure. It may be that one of these ‘submethods’ invokes printing to System.err / stderr. Is there a way to block all the printing related to the method? I found [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799006/in-java-how-can-i-redirect-system-out-to-null-then-back-to-stdout-again) which explains how to do this by temporarily redirecting System.err altogether, but I fear that this could lead to other errors (that I do want to track) not to appear in the console.

Comment: Short answer: No. Longer answer: Yes. Temporarily redirect `System.err` altogether. Yes. It could lead to other errors. The only other option I see, is to remove all of the println calls in `method()`. Or, better, use an actual logger instead of writing everything to `PrintStream`(s).

Comment: @Elliot: My problem is that ‘method()’ invokes a method from a library which I am not in control over. /

Comment: A custom stream that tries to filter out the things that shouldn't be printed and things that should be printed. The JVM can't know what you consider important info and what not, it just has the single `System.err`.

Comment: The problem is that `System.err` is **global** and anything running concurrently will also be redirected.  It might be better to disassemble the library and manually change its operation.  Or ask the library owner to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to store the original PrintStream and Override before methods' call and restore its back after the invocation

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Before methods' invocation
        final PrintStream orgErr = System.err;

        System.setErr(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {

            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {

            }
        }));

        callMethod();

        // After methods' invocation
        System.setErr(orgErr);
    }

    static void callMethod() {
        try {
            throw new RuntimeException("failed");
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're running multiple threads, using the method in the post you linked to should work (Except System.setErr instead of System.setOut

```
public void method(){
    //This submethod will print errors
    submethod1();

    PrintStream original = System.err;
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(new OutputStream(){
        public void write(int i){ }
    }));

    //This submethod will NOT print errors
    submethod2();

    System.setErr(original);

    //This submethod will print errors
    submethod3();
}
```

As long as you set back to the original before you call any submethods that you do want errors from, you should be fine